# Flink 1.3 running a single job on YARN how to set the number of Task Slots per TaskManager

Tags: apache-flink

I am running a single flink job on Yarn as descriped [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/yarn_setup.html#run-a-single-flink-job-on-yarn).

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 3 -ytm 12000
```

I can set the number of yarn nodes / task managers with the above parameter `-yn`. However I want to know whether it is possible to set the number of task slots *per task manager*. When I use the parallelsim (`-p`) parameter it only sets the overall parallelism. And the number of task slots is computed by dividing this value by the number of provided task managers. I tried using the dynamic properties (`-yD`) parameter which is supposed to "allow the user to specify additional configuration values" like this:

```
 -yD -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=8
```

But this does not overwrite the value given in the `flink-conf.yaml`.
Is there any way to specify the number of task slots per TaskManager when running a single on flink (other than changing the config file)? 
Also is there a documentation which dynamic properties are valid using the `-yD` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the settings of yarn-session, [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/yarn_setup.html#start-a-session), prefixed by `y` to submit Flink job on YARN cluster. For example the command,

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 5 -yjm 768 -ytm 1400 -ys 2 -yqu streamQ my_program.jar
```

will submit `my_program.jar` Flink application with `5` *containers*, `768m` memory for the *jobmanager*, `1400m` memory and `2` cpu core for *taskmanagers*, each and will use the resources of nodemanagers on predefined YARN queue `streamQ`. See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974877/why-flink-container-vcore-size-is-always-1/50085522#50085522) post for other important information.