# FLINK : Deployment took more than 60 seconds

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am new to flink and trying to deploy my jar on EMR cluster. I have used 3 node cluster (1 master and 2 slaves) with their default configuration. I have not done any configuration changes and sticking with default configuration. On running the following command on my master node:

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 2 -c Main /home/hadoop/myjar-0.1.jar
```

I am getting the following error:

```
INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor- Deployment took more than 60 seconds. Please check if the requested resources are available in the YARN cluster
```

Can anyone please explain what could be the possible reason for this error?

Answer (score 4):

As you didn't determine any resources (Memory, CPU core), I guess it's because the YARN cluster has not the desired resource, especially memory.
Try submitting your jar file using the following type of commands:

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 5 -yjm 768 -ytm 1400 -ys 2 -yqu streamQ my_program.jar
```

You can find more information about the command [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/yarn_setup.html#start-a-session)

You can check application logs in YARN WebUI to see what's the problem exactly.

Also, check this posts:

- [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176762/flink-1-3-running-a-single-job-on-yarn-how-to-set-the-number-of-task-slots-per-t/50188964#50188964)
- [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974877/why-flink-container-vcore-size-is-always-1/50085522#50085522)